# Checking for availability in weekly schedule spanning across multiple days

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, timestamp

I have weekly availability schedules designed like the following:

- Saturday - 12:00 - 00:00
- Sunday - 00:00 - 10:00
- Thursday - 12:00 - 21:00

This user for example is available on only 3 days and between the specified timestamps. I have both from and to timestamps that need to be between the availability intervals for a user to be available.

My problem is that if 2 intervals across 2 different days are continuous, how can I check that it's available? For example, Saturday and Sunday produce a continuous availability interval, how can I check that an interval starting on Saturday at 22:00 and ending on Sunday at 02:00 (which should be available) is actually available?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the problem you have is with comparing a time period between two given date/time points with multiple separate availability time preiods between date/time points which may overlap or be consecutive, to see if the required period is completely covered by one or more availability periods.

In dealing with similar problems in the past I have found a good way to deal with this is to pre-process the multiple, separate availability periods in order to join up overlapping or contiguous periods into "normalised" larger ones, so that you end up with a minimal set of availability periods that cover all the times that are defined in the original set. Then it becomes much easier to check the required period against the normalised set.

This also has the advantage (although this is not stated in your requirement) that you can add availability from multiple providers (e.g. if you are looking for continuous "cover" rather than a specific single resource).

Here is some sample code that illustrates this approach. Please beware, this code is not exhaustively tested.

```
/**
 * A class definition for an availability period
 * @param {Date} start date/time 
 * @param {Date} end date/time
 */
var Period = function( start, end ){
    // Set the start and end dates
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;

    // Set the start and end timestamps (for faster comparison)
    this.startTime = start.getTime();
    this.endTime = end.getTime();

    // Flag to indicate if this availability period is completely contained within another
    this.contained = false;

    // Check validity of start and end
    if( this.startTime > this.endTime ){
        throw new Error( "Start time of period cannot be later than end time");
    }

    // Function to check if this period includes a required period
    this.includes = function( period ){
        if( period.startTime >= this.startTime && period.endTime <= this.endTime ) return true;
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * A class definition for a period store that accepts addition
 * of multiple available periods and merges overlapping periods,
 * and has a function to check if a specified period is available
 */
var PeriodStore = function(){
    this.periods = [];
    this.calllevel = 0;

    // Member function to add a new period to the collection
    // of periods - if it overlaps with an existing period
    // both will be merged into a single spanning period.
    this.addAvailabilityPeriod = function( newPeriod ){
        // wind up the call count (see below)
        this.calllevel++;

        let self = this;

        newPeriod.contained = false;

        // compare the new period to all the existing periods
        self.periods.forEach( function( oldPeriod ){

            // only check if both periods are not contained in another
            if ( !newPeriod.contained && !oldPeriod.contained ){


                if( oldPeriod.includes( newPeriod ) ){
                    newPeriod.contained = true;
                } else
                if( newPeriod.includes( oldPeriod ) ){
                    oldPeriod.contained = true;
                } else
                if( oldPeriod.startTime <= newPeriod.endTime 
                    && oldPeriod.startTime > newPeriod.startTime 
                    && oldPeriod.endTime > newPeriod.endTime ){

                    // replace the two periods with a new one spanning both
                    newPeriod.contained = true;
                    oldPeriod.contained = true;
                    // Recursive call to add the new merged period to the collection
                    self.addAvailabilityPeriod( new Period(newPeriod.start, oldPeriod.end) );

                } else 
                if( newPeriod.startTime <= oldPeriod.endTime 
                    && newPeriod.startTime > oldPeriod.startTime 
                    && newPeriod.endTime > oldPeriod.endTime ){

                    // replace the two periods with a new one spanning both
                    newPeriod.contained = true;
                    oldPeriod.contained = true;

                    // Recursive call to add the new merged period to the collection
                    self.addAvailabilityPeriod( new Period(oldPeriod.start, newPeriod.end) )

                }
            }
        } )

        // If the new period is not contained within 
        // another period, then add it to the periods 
        // collection
        if( !newPeriod.contained ) self.periods.push( newPeriod );

        // unwind the call count
        this.calllevel--;

        // Clean up the list to remove any previously-existing periods that
        // are now contained withing any new periods.
        if (this.calllevel == 0 ){
            for( var ix = self.periods.length - 1; ix >= 0; ix-- ){
                if( self.periods[ix].contained ){
                    console.log( "Removing contained period", self.periods[ix] )
                    self.periods.splice( ix, 1 );
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // Function to check if a given period is contained
    // within any of the available periods in the store
    // and return the containing period if so, null if not
    this.checkAvailability = function( checkperiod ){
        var self = this;

        console.log( "Checking availability", checkperiod );
        for( var ix = 0; ix < self.periods.length ; ix++ ){

            if( self.periods[ix].includes( checkperiod ) ){
                return self.periods[ix];
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

}

// ------------------ TESTING -------------------------


// Create array of available periods
var availablePeriods = [
    new Period( new Date( "2017-08-01T07:00:00Z"),  new Date( "2017-08-01T08:00:00Z" ) )
    , new Period( new Date( "2017-08-02T07:00:00Z"), new Date( "2017-08-02T08:00:00Z" ) )
    , new Period( new Date( "2017-08-01T08:00:00Z"), new Date( "2017-08-02T06:55:00Z" ) )
]

// Create the period store
var periodStore = new PeriodStore();

// Add all the available periods to the store
availablePeriods.forEach( function(period){

    periodStore.addAvailabilityPeriod( period );

})

// Report the available periods
console.log( periodStore );

// Check availability between two date / times
var fm = new Date( "2017-08-01T07:30:00Z" );
var to = new Date( "2017-08-01T08:30:00Z" );

console.log( periodStore.checkAvailability( new Period( fm, to ) ) );

to = new Date( "2017-08-02T09:30:00Z")

console.log( periodStore.checkAvailability( new Period( fm, to ) ) ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks @RobG - I have added some explanatory notes at the beginning to set out my understanding of the problem set by the OP. Hopefully that will help to clarify the approach. I take the point about the dates - it worked OK when I ran it on node.js in Windows Server, but I did notice that it assumed the given dates/times were local time (BST) prior to conversion so they were adjusted to UTC when the Date objects were created. Clearly I will need to be more careful with time literals! Many thanks!